# Handling max(ID) in a concurrent environment

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am new to web application programming and handling concurrency using an RDBMS like SQL Server. I am using SQL Server 2005 Express Edition.

I am generating employee code in which the last four digits come from this query:

```
SELECT max(ID) FROM employees WHERE district = "XYZ";
```

I am not following how to handle issues that might arise due to concurrent connections. Many users can pick same max(ID) and while one user clicks "Save Record", the ID might have already been occupied by another user.

How to handle this issue?

Comment: You use an autoincrement column, or you make the query transactional so that only one executes at a time.

Comment: You fetch the max ID for a given district?  What do you do with that ID? Is the ID column an identity column?  When do you execute the query? Right after the insert and you want to use the newly created ID for something?

Comment: That ID is combined with other things to make a ten digit numeric code. A GenerateID() function is called when user clicks Save button.

Comment: Can you show the code for generateid()? There might be alternative ways to do this. Is ID an auto incremented identity column?

Comment: Yes it is an auto-incremented column. There is nothing special in the GenerateId() function. It picks 4 digits of current year, two digits of district code and four digits are reserved for max(ID). This makes it a 10 digits employee code.

Comment: You should use scope_identity() to get the newly inserted id and use that to generate the employee code. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx

Comment: @Mikael Eriksson: Can you please post your tip as answer below instead of a comment. It seems a nice tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two ways of doing what you want. The fact that you might end up with unique constraint violation on `EmpCode` I will leave you to worry about :).

**1.** Use [`scope_identity()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) to get the last inserted ID and use that to calculate `EmpCode`.

Table definition:

```
create table Employees
(
  ID int identity primary key,
  Created datetime not null default getdate(),
  DistrictCode char(2) not null,
  EmpCode char(10) not null default left(newid(), 10) unique
)
```

Add one row to Employees. Should be done in a transaction to be sure that you will not be left with the default random value from `left(newid(), 10)` in `EmpCode`:

```
declare @ID int

insert into Employees (DistrictCode) values ('AB')

set @ID = scope_identity()

update Employees
set EmpCode = cast(year(Created) as char(4))+DistrictCode+right(10000+@ID, 4)
where ID = @ID
```

**2.** Make `EmpCode` a [computed column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186241%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx).

Table definition:

```
create table Employees
(
  ID int identity primary key,
  Created datetime not null default getdate(),
  DistrictCode char(2) not null,
  EmpCode as cast(year(Created) as char(4))+DistrictCode+right(10000+ID, 4) unique
)
```

Add one row to Employees:

```
insert into Employees (DistrictCode) values ('AB')
```

Answer (score 2):

It is a bad idea to use MAX, because with a proper locking mechanism, you will not be able to insert rows in multiple threads for the same district.
If it is OK for you that you can only create one user at a time, and if your tests show that the MAX scales up even with a lot of users per district, it may be ok to use it.
Long story short, dealing with identies, as much as possible, you should rely on IDENTITY.  Really.

But if it is not possible, one solution is to handle IDs in a separate table.

```
Create Table DistrictID (
    DistrictCode char(2),
    LastID Int,
    Constraint PK_DistrictCode Primary Key Clustered (DistrictCode)
);
```

Then you increment the LastID counter.  It is important that incrementing IDs is a transaction separated to the user creation transaction if you want to create many users in parallel threads.  You can limit to have only the ID generation in sequence.

The code can look like this:

```
Create Procedure usp_GetNewId(@DistrictCode char(2), @NewId Int Output)
As

Set NoCount On;
Set Transaction Isolation Level Repeatable Read;
Begin Tran;
Select @NewId = LastID From DistrictID With (XLock) Where DistrictCode = @DistrictCode;
Update DistrictID Set LastID = LastID + 1 Where DistrictCode = @DistrictCode;
Commit Tran;
```

The **Repeatable Read** and **XLOCK** keywords are the minimum that you need to avoid two threads to get the same ID.
If the table does not have all districts, you will need to change the **Repeatable Read** into a **Serializable**, and fork the **Update** with a **Insert**.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done through [Transaction Isolation Levels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx).  For instance, if you specify SERIALIZABLE as the level then other transactions will be blocked so that you aren't running into this problem.

If I did not understand your question correctly, please let me know.